# Laptop HDMI is duplicated on two screens, instead of extended across them

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, duplicate

My laptop is a DELL LATITUDE 3004.

I was using it connected to two monitors (one in HDMI one in VGA). So I can work easily with my desktop extended on two screens.

Now I bought an HDMI splitter, so I can use the configuration HDMI + HDMI. However I see one desktop on the left one on the right and not one extended.

I tried changing the settings, but I couldn't get it work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason why you are seeing two of the same images here is because you purchased what is known as an `HDMI Splitter`.  Splitters work by taking a single input signal and, well, 'splitting' them out to multiple inputs.

Since from your original question you want to be able to have two desktops, I would suggest hooking up your laptop to a monitor that supports it via HDMI (usually Mini-HDMI or even USB-C these days) to your monitor, or using a USB to HDMI adapter, or even USB-C to HDMI adapter from your computer to the monitor. This would allow your machine to display the image on  your computer, as well as that on the monitor, even in extended mode.

Comment: HELLO! THANKS.My monitor are not provided of MINI HDMI OR USB C. But my laptop yes. So which product do you suggest to fix the problem?
"USB to HDMI adapter, or even USB-C to HDMI" Do you have some link? on AMAZON for example?